# Understanding /var/log/auth.log in Ubuntu

Tags: authentication, pam

I am having an hard time understanding some lines inside my auth.log file from Ubuntu. Can you help me breaking down the pieces of this one?

```
pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
```

pkexec is the executable that launches pam_unix (?)
pam_unix is a system call used to authenticate the user (?)
I can't figure out what polkit-1 session is

What does session opened mean? That someone has tried to login or someone has succeeded to login?

Is there any way to investigate from where this request of authentication came from? More log lines below:

Shortly after those timestamps the entire home folder was removed by someone. I was connected through ssh remotely and suddenly the connection stopped working. I suspect someone got physical access to the laptop (if it was someone from the lab he could have known the password to my user which also had sudo privileges). I had to call a friend to reboot the laptop and after that we "found" all the missing files.

```
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 06:30:36 laptop pkexec[26293]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 07:03:36 laptop pkexec[26507]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Jun  4 07:56:50 laptop unix_chkpwd[27106]: password check failed for user (giulia)
Jun  4 07:56:50 laptop compiz: pam_unix(unity:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1001 euid=1001 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=giulia
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1001)
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
Jun  4 08:24:36 laptop pkexec[27821]: giulia: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/giulia] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

Comment: "_if it was someone from the lab he could have known the password to my user_" all bets are off. If you share your password details with someone else, and it's got root access then anything could have happened - including the removal of lines from `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: "_I had to call a friend to reboot the laptop and after that we "found" all the missing files_" the chances are you're using per-user encryption of home directories. In some instances this cannot handle the same user account logging in (and out) at the same time as it's logged in elsewhere. I suspect this is what you saw.

Comment: Yes I know that all bets are off, however this questions is not to understand what happened, but rather to learn something from this story. The question asks specifically what are the entries in the log file.

Comment: Regarding your other comment, if that was the case I would expect to see the home folder again after logging in with ssh another time.

Comment: Re the log file, you cannot trust any of the log files if someone had access to your system.

Comment: Re home directory, probably yes. I'm not sure enough to write an answer

Comment: @roaima you didn't understand my point. "The question asks specifically what are the entries in the log file." like, what is the meaning of the strings? what is pam_unix? what is the polkit policy? you are fcusing on a side part of my question that I wrote just to give some context. thanks!